# How to return asp:repeater count

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have searching implemented in my app, and it goes to a results page where the results populate a table through an asp:repeater.  I'll include the code below.

C#

```
namespace WebApplication {
    public partial class SearchResults : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (Request.Params["searchterm"] != null) {
                ResultLabel.Text = "Search results for: " + Request.Params["searchterm"];
                string searchTerm = Request.Params["searchterm"];
                int results = 0; //If I were to set it on back end
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CurrencyDb"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SearchProc", con)) {
                        try {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchTerm", searchTerm);
                            con.Open();
                            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            sda.Fill(ds);
                            ResultsTableRepeater.DataSource = ds;
                            ResultsTableRepeater.DataBind();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException sqlex) {
                            throw new Exception("SQL Exception loading data from database. " + sqlex.Message);
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex) {
                            throw new Exception("Error loading results data from database. " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
    <asp:Label ID="ResultLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="ResultsTableRepeater" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="td-table-bordered">
                <th>Currency Id</th>
                <th>Component</th>
                <th>Version</th>
                <th>Vendor</th>
                <th>Tech Owner</th>
                <th>Tech Contact</th>
                <th>Fiscal Consideration</th>
                <th>Currency Status</th>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("CurrencyId") %></td>
                <td><asp:HyperLink ID="UpdateLink" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("CurrencyId", "http://10.155.54.101/Update?CurrencyId={0}") %>' runat="server" Target="_blank"><%# Eval("Model") %></asp:HyperLink></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Version") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Vendor") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Tech Owner") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Tech Contact") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("FiscalConsideration") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Status") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>

            <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

What I would like to do is print a number how many results were returned in the footer.  But I can't seem to find a way to do that throughout all of my searching, despite it seeming like it should be a simple task.

Is there a way, whether it be in the C# code behind or in the aspx directly to print how the amount of results at the end?  It would be easy if there were a while(reader.read) loop to increment a counter, however that's not the case.

Thanks in advance so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of `sda.Fill(ds);`:

As the [documentation for Fill says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value: The number of rows successfully added to or refreshed in the DataSet.

Thus:

```
int rowsReturned = sda.Fill(ds);
```

Then you can assign the value in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar issue here:
[Determine the repeater row count in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999825/determine-the-repeater-row-count-in-asp-net)

Hope this helps you out! Should just be able to use their solution anywhere in your codebehind to get the Count, and then display it where ever you need it in your footer (assuming your repeater is already populated when you try to get the count).